# How to return to main activity when no action in the second activity Pragmatically

Tags: android, events, android-activity, timer, back-button

Let's say that the user has invoked the 2nd activity from the main activity.
he/she did not do anything on the 2nd activity for a $period of time.
How to return to the main activity Pragmatically and not keeping the 2nd activity showing
I am using this for a kiosk application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a handler to post a runnable with a delay.

```
Handler h = new Handler();

Runnable r = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        finish();
    }
};

private void resetTimeout()
{
    h.removeCallbacks(r);
    h.postDelayed(r, 10*60*1000); // delay 10 minutes
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    resetTimeout();
};
```

Comment: where should i implement this? in the OnCreate in the 2nd activity?

Comment: in the 2nd activity, yes. you can implement it onResume() as I did above, or in onCreate(), then call resetTimeout() whenever you register user activity.

Comment: it fired a run time exception SuperNotCalledException

Comment: add `super.onResume();` as the first line inside of your onResume() mtehod.